# Do I have to rebuild my Docker image every time I want to make a change to app settings?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, app-config, appsettings

We distribute Docker images of our .Net Core Web API to clients.
By setting the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable to X in the client's Kubernetes Helm Chart, the correct environment settings in `appsettings.X.json` get picked up.  This all works nicely.

But what happens if the client needs to change one of the settings in `appsettings.X.json`?  We don't want them to rebuild the Docker image.

Can someone offer a better architecture here?

Comment: can you add some more detail

Comment: @cemkaan What more detail do you need here?

Comment: Injecting the settings using a Kubernetes ConfigMap would be a pretty typical approach.

Comment: @cemkaan Basically I'm asking if there's a clever way to do environment-specific configuration using the standard Microsoft recommended appsettings.json files, that doesn't require us to rebuild our Docker images every time we want to make a config change.  Hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

The most common practice is to get settings directly from the environment. Thus instead of a settings.json you would read from the environment (you could have defaults too. Another solution would be to use http://www.confd.io/

Comment: Yeah we thought of this but prefer the appsettings functionality provided by Microsoft as it allows some nice "overriding" features.  As our app is also consumed by SaaS clients and developers, we would also have to inject the config into those environments as well.  So it gets a bit messy.  I prefer to keep all the config in the appsettings but perhaps it's not possible in this use case.

Comment: another idea is to mount the settings

Comment: Not a bad idea but clients would have to do the mount...not a great user experience.